# How to access an object in a list by property?

Tags: python, oop, list, object

Consider a list of objects and a method that works on one object:

```
beers = []
beers.append(Beer('Carlsberg', 'tasty'))
beers.append(Beer('Guinness', 'bitter'))
beers.append(Beer('Leffe', 'perfect'))

def howIsBeer (name):
    taste = ???
    print taste

Class Beer:
    def __init__ (self, name, taste):
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste
```

How would the `howIsBeer()` method go about getting the taste of a beer if it is provided only with the beer name? **My first inclination is to iterate the `beers` list, but being Python I suspect that there is a more direct method. Is there?**

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a `dict` ?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to deal with the situation in which I will have any arbitrary unique object property. Each property might also have a phone number or a geographical coordinates field (each unique). I might not always be searching on a "primary key", though I am restricting this to properties that are unique across objects.

Comment: Then you sequentially scan the list as you stated, create multiple support dicts, or look into storing it in a sqlite3 memory DB

Comment: You've misspelt Carlsberg and Leffe :)

Comment: @NPE: That's only because I had no idea how to spell Guinness and googled it. The other two I was sure about!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sake of completeness, I have found a way to use a [Linq-like single-line statement](http://codepad.org/0H6wom4T) which also has the advantage of being a bit easier to read:

```
taste = [b.taste for b in beers if b.name==name][0]
```

The `[0]` at the end is to return the first item, since the query returns a list of matching items. So to get the whole list:

```
[b.taste for b in beers if b.name==name]
```

This is why I love Python!

Answer (score 3):

Can't really think of any better way, simply use a `for`-loop.

```
def howIsBeer(name):
    for beer in beers:
        if beer.name == name:
            return beer.taste

In [1]: howIsBeer("Carlsburg")
Out[1]: tasty
```

Also notice, that keyword `class` is written with small `c`. You will also have to define your class **before** you use it for creating instances.

**Edit**:
One way, as suggested in the commments, would be to define dictionaries. If you find it useful, you can use the code below. Notice, however, this is only recommended if you have **HUGE** amount of Beer objects and performance speed is really important for you. Else use the first code provided

```
class Beer:
    names = {}
    def __init__(self, name, taste):
        Beer.names[name] = self
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste

In [3]: Beer.names["Carlsburg"].taste
Out[3]: tasty
```

Comment: You don't need to use multiple dictionaries - per say - you have one where the name is the `Beer.name` and the properties are stored as a dictionary. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703515/432913) below.

Comment: Your way of using dictionaries for this case is the worst way there is, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13703439/1632861) above.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the loop. The second code example is useful only if I know beforehand on which property I will need to search, and of course only if the Beer class is my own code.

Comment: @Mahi This answer is misleading though, the way you have done this, each `Beer` class creates its own dictionary, with just one `Beer` object in it, and the `Beer.name` variable stored twice.

Comment: @dotancohen You could create a dictionary for each value - but as I mentioned, that's only recommended for **HUGE** lists, like 10000 objects or such. With a quick inherit, you could use it for any class tho :) But don't use it if the first one suits you.

Comment: @will Just wondering, you got 2 accounts or who idiot is upping your comments and answer? "each `Beer` class" there is only one class named `Beer`, and each instance of `Beer` will be added to that one class' ONE `names` dictionary. Try it.

Comment: @Mahi: I'm one of the idiots who upvoted will. I upvoted you both for both mentioning the solution: to iterate over the `beers` list. I accepted your answer though as you expanded on the question, as opposed to will turning the example into an XY problem. Why are you offended if will gets an upvote for being helpful? Are the two of you in competition?

Comment: @dotancohen Well the reason for your upvote was good one then, rest of his answer is bullsh*t. But yeah thanks for the accept, good luck with your program. :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll see you around, I'm going through your past Python answers to see what I can learn.

Answer (score 3):

Just loop through the list and check for each one.

You need to move the code around a little though, as the `class def` needs to be above the use of the class, and also it uses a small `c`. You should also watch out for the case where it's not recognised.

You also spelt Carlsberg wrong :/

```
class Beer:
    def __init__ (self, name, taste):
        self.name = name
        self.taste = taste



beers = []
beers.append(Beer('Carlsberg', 'tasty'))
beers.append(Beer('Guinness', 'bitter'))
beers.append(Beer('Lef', 'perfect'))


def howIsBeer (name):

    taste = "I have no idea"

    for beer in beers:
        if beer.name == name:
            taste = beer.taste

    print taste



howIsBeer("Carlsberg") # tasty
```

I'd do it like this though (using the dictionaries here allows for the flexibility of having more than one property):

```
beers = {}
beers["Lef"] = {"taste": "tasty"}
beers["Staropramen"] = {"taste": "tasty"}
beers["Peroni"] = {"taste": "tasty"}
beers["Coors Light"] = {"taste": "What is this?!"}


def howIsBeer (name):

    taste = "I have no idea"

    if name in beers:
        taste = beers[name]["taste"]

    print taste



howIsBeer("Lef")
```

If you just want to store the tastes, then you could do this:

```
beers = {}
beers["Lef"] = "tasty"
beers["Staropramen"] = "tasty"
beers["Peroni"] = "tasty"
beers["Coors Light"] = "What is this?!"


def howIsBeer (name):

    taste = "I have no idea"

    if name in beers:
        taste = beers[name]

    print taste



howIsBeer("Lef")
```

If you are looking to store a series of objects - as you mention in the question - then you want a dictionary of objects - **not** a dictionary that is a variable of the class.

i.e.

```
beers = {}

def add_beer(beer):
    beers[beer.name] = beer
```

then to get data on the beer you're looking at;

```
if beer in beers:
    beers[beer].taste
```

This can be extended to any object type, and i believe is exactly what you're looking for;

e.g.

```
cheeses = {}
add_cheese(cheese):
    cheeses[cheese.name] = cheese
```

where

```
class cheese:
    def __init__(self, name, smelliness, hardness, colour, country):
        self.name = name
        self.smelliness = smelliness
        self.hardness = hardness
        self.colour = colour
        self.country = country
```

Comment: How exactly is this a) using dictionaries b) different than my answer?

Comment: @Mahi I was editing my post - posted the comment just beforehand - sorry!

Comment: @Mahi The first bit isn't no, you got there a little faster, i just included something to account for when `name` is not in `beers` - in which case your `howIsBeer` will never return

Comment: If the name is not in beers, my `howIsBeer` will return `None`, which means that the beer was not found.

Comment: And to your dictionary edit, that's simply wrong, bad, and awful. Don't ever, ever use dictionaries like that, if you can use objects instead. That's why classes were designed in the first place!

Comment: Thank you will. It looks like I will have to use the loop.

Comment: @Mahi I'm sorry, but I disagree with you. Why add the bother of creating a class when you are only looking to store a small number of properties. And if it's only one property, then you could just store that.

Comment: @will: The question in the OP was contrived to illustrate a point. Making a more intricate class would have only distracted from the point of the question. For purposes of "how to do X" the question in the OP was the simplest example of X. Example questions are not XY questions, even if the particular simplified case could be accomplished more succinctly.

Comment: @will Now I'm certain, you got two accounts, one for up voting yourself. Your disagreement doesn't matter. To begin with, the OP mentioned that he's got multiple attributes in his actual program (which is not obviously beers). Also, if there's only one property, you're still supposed to create a class, that's what they're for. Your way is terrible, never use it.

Comment: @mahi I don't have two accounts? I don't know why you're taking this so personally, and being so confrontational...